# Switching workspaces using ctrl + alt + (left/right) but I have to click on window to focus on it everytime

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have recently upgraded into Ubuntu 23.04. And when I switch workspaces using
CTRL + ALT + (LEFT/ RIGHT) it switches workspace but....

I have to click on window to focus and work on it everytime I switch workspace. Now, that kinda goes annoying to click on window everytime you switch.

is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your question is unclear in a number of respects. Using a `Try Ubuntu` instance, I can navigate easily between workspaces using the shortcut outlined by you. However, if I have two apps open in a workspace, to move one to another workspace, that has to be the active window to be successful and the shortcut is Shift+Super+PageDown to move it. The active window is shown in the System Tray  to the right of Activities. Is that what you mean? Also, [edit] your question to indicate which version/distro you upgraded from and to and the method used to perform the upgrade.

Comment: I'm actually facing the same issue. Ubuntu 23.04 comes with Gnome Shell 44. The change-log reports improved focus handling on workspace switching. 
It seems like we are experiencing the opposite effect. 
https://www.phoronix.com/news/GNOME-Shell-Mutter-44-Beta